# Which are the most reliable pronunciation guidelines?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling

I know there are no completely consistent pronunciation rules in English. But as an English language learner, I would like to have a set of guidelines to use as a fall-back when I am unsure about a word's pronunciation.

Among all the guidelines I found on the web, the two most complete are [PronRules.pdf](http://files.myopera.com/toefl56/blog/PronRules.pdf?1295709680) and [Hou tu pranownse Inglish](http://www.zompist.com/spell.html).

Do you know of any better guidelines than these two?

Comment: We have a good FAQ here: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english/739. Check out the Dictionaries and Websites sections. ;^)

Comment: I recommend looking it up in a dictionary that contains pronunciation information such as [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/).

Comment: It shows the pronunciation of each words, but it doesn't contain guidelines about English words' pronunciation.